# SSO using http headers in GitLab CE

Tags: http, authentication, http-headers, single-sign-on, gitlab

Does anyone know if it's possible to enable http header-based authentication in the community edition of GitLab? If not, is there a plugin that provides this functionality. I haven't been able to locate anything in my searches.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find something useful?